# Как при нажатии клавиши записать ее в переменную

Tags: javascript, html

В общем суть заключается в том, что при открытой странице(веб) при нажатии клавиш любых нужно, чтобы они записывались, в переменную, и затем при нажатии клавиши enter тебя перекидывало на другую страницу.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeypress = function(e) {
        e = e || window.e;
        var shifr= e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
             window.open('window2.html');
        }

            }

</script>
```

я знаю он кривой, но я примерно пытался сделать, подскажите пожалуйста как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно в каком виде вы хотите сохранять уже нажатые клавиши, можно реализовать так:

```
var keyLog = [];
document.onkeypress = (e)=>{
    const k = e.keyCode || e.which;
    keyLog.push( k );
    if( k == 13 ) location.href = 'window2.html';
}
```

нажатые клавиши сохраняются в массив keyLog.